# I'm having an error while using cargo to install anchor-cli and avm in WSL Ubuntu, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rust-cargo, vscode-remote, anchor-solana

I already have Rust, Solana and Yarn installed successfully. The command I am trying to use is this one:

```
cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor avm --locked --force
```

The error message I get back is this:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.77`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/tmp/cargo-installk91rY7/release/build/openssl-sys-af9ec1f75a721e6b/build-script-main` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rustc-cfg=const_fn
  cargo:rustc-cfg=openssl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DIR
  OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  run pkg_config fail: "`\"pkg-config\" \"--libs\" \"--cflags\" \"openssl\"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1\nerror: could not find system library 'openssl' required by the 'openssl-sys' crate\n\n--- stderr\nPackage openssl was not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `openssl.pc'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\nNo package 'openssl' found\n"

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '

  Could not find directory of OpenSSL installation, and this `-sys` crate cannot
  proceed without this knowledge. If OpenSSL is installed and this crate had
  trouble finding it,  you can set the `OPENSSL_DIR` environment variable for the
  compilation process.

  Make sure you also have the development packages of openssl installed.
  For example, `libssl-dev` on Ubuntu or `openssl-devel` on Fedora.

  If you're in a situation where you think the directory *should* be found
  automatically, please open a bug at https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl
  and include information about your system as well as this message.

  $HOST = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  $TARGET = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  openssl-sys = 0.9.77

  ', /home/leodonoso/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-sys-0.9.77/build/find_normal.rs:191:5
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `avm v0.25.0 (https://github.com/project-serum/anchor#66e4295f)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installk91rY7`
```

Similarly I tried installing the CLI with this command:

```
cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor --tag v0.24.1 anchor-cli --locked
```

and I got this message:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.72`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/tmp/cargo-installBvI9yh/release/build/openssl-sys-e13f4366f032967d/build-script-main` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rustc-cfg=const_fn
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DIR
  OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  run pkg_config fail: "`\"pkg-config\" \"--libs\" \"--cflags\" \"openssl\"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1\nerror: could not find system library 'openssl' required by the 'openssl-sys' crate\n\n--- stderr\nPackage openssl was not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `openssl.pc'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\nNo package 'openssl' found\n"

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '

  Could not find directory of OpenSSL installation, and this `-sys` crate cannot
  proceed without this knowledge. If OpenSSL is installed and this crate had
  trouble finding it,  you can set the `OPENSSL_DIR` environment variable for the
  compilation process.

  Make sure you also have the development packages of openssl installed.
  For example, `libssl-dev` on Ubuntu or `openssl-devel` on Fedora.

  If you're in a situation where you think the directory *should* be found
  automatically, please open a bug at https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl
  and include information about your system as well as this message.

  $HOST = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  $TARGET = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  openssl-sys = 0.9.72

  ', /home/leodonoso/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-sys-0.9.72/build/find_normal.rs:180:5
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `anchor-cli v0.24.1 (https://github.com/project-serum/anchor?tag=v0.24.1#d491f0ba)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installBvI9yh`
```

Please help

In the installation page, it says that I should run this command for Ubuntu if I had an error:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config build-essential libudev-dev
```

Already did that. It didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (install libssl-dev):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config build-essential libudev-dev libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of both error messages, it tells you what the problem is (`cargo` is really great about this, so learn to trust it when it's telling you something!).

The problem is that you don't have OpenSSL development packages installed. I don't have WSL to test with, but running `apt-get update && apt-get install openssl libssl-dev`, should get you up and running.

If that doesn't, then the second suggestion in the error message (setting the environment variable) should do the trick, but you should also open an issue at the provided link in the message.